# Any possible way to receive an alert of Windows Server being "unresponsive"?

Tags: windows, windows-service, alert

We currently use ServiceNow to have many alerts like ping, 100% CPU/RAM utilization, disk space being almost full, etc. but we are investigating if we can receive an alert when the OS is "unresponsive", that is, cannot connect by RDP or VMware console (black screen). We have experienced Windows Servers in which the IIS or other APP services are still working, but we have to reboot the OS in order to access it.

Is there a critical Windows Server service that could be identified as being "unresponsive" by the characteristics mentioned?